# Homotopy type of the affine Grassmannian and of the Beilinson-Drinfeld Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-representation-theory

The affine Grassmannian of a complex reductive group $G$ (for simplicity one can assume $G=GL_n$) admits the structure of a complex topological space. More precisely, the functor $$X\mapsto |X^{an}|$$ that associates to a scheme locally of finite type the underlying topological space of its analytification ([SGA1, XII, 1]) can be left-Kan-extended to a functor $PSh(Sch)\to Top$, and therefore applied to the ind-scheme $Gr_G$.

Some topological properties of this space are known: its connected components are in bijection with the topological fundamental group $\pi_1(G)$ ([Beilinson-Drinfel'd, *Quantization of Hitchin's integrable system and Hecke eigensheaves*, Proposition 4.5.4]). The étale fundamental group (which is the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group) of each orbit in $Gr_G$ under the left action of $L^+G$ is trivial (Richarz, *Affine Grassmannians and the Geometric Satake Equivalences*, proof of Proposition 3.1).

Also, $|Gr_G^{an}|$ is known to be homotopy equivalent to a polynomial loop space ([Zhu, An introduction to the affine Grassmannian and the Geometric Satake Equivalence] and [Pressley/Segal, Loop Groups, Sec. 8.3]).

However, my knowledge essentially stops here. For example, the homotopy groups of this polynomial loop space are unknown to me.

Has anyone ever written or thought about the topology of the affine Grassmannian in further detail? Relevant questions to me are the following:

1. What are the fundamental groups of the connected components of $|Gr_G^{an}|$?
2. The cohomology of the affine Grassmannian is much more studied and used than its homotopic properties. Is there any chance that the connected components of $|Gr_G^{an}|$ satisfy conditions like "being a simple space", which often allows homotopical issues to be translated into cohomological issues, by means of the homological Whitehead theorem?

Needless to say, the answer to such questions for the Beilinson-Drinfel'd Grassmannian will probably be more difficult. However, any ideas or references in this more sophisticated context would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.