# Stratified fibration property of the "Ran" affine Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, geometric-representation-theory, affine-grassmannian

Let us consider the so-called Ran Grassmannian $Gr_{Ran}$, i.e. the geometric object defined e.g. in [Zhu, An Introduction to the affine Grassmannian and the Geometric Satake equivalence, Definition 3.3.2]. This is an object associated to a complex smooth curve X and a complex reductive group $G$. It parametrizes the choice of a finite system of points of $X$, a $G$-torsor on X, and a trivialization of that torsor away from the chosen system of points in $X$.

The Ran Grassmannian is the colimit of a certain diagram of ind-schemes whose vertices are called the Beilinson-Drinfeld Grassmannians (see again Zhu, 3.1). The Ran space $Ran(X)$ is the space of finite systems of points in $X$. We have a natural map from $Gr_{Ran}$ to $Ran(X)$.

Consider the "cardinality" stratification on the Ran space: i.e., a stratum consists of all systems of points in the variety having the same cardinality. Let us work in the complex analytic topology. In this setting, I have been told that the map $Gr_{Ran}\to Ran(X)$ is a "stratified fibration", in the sense that

a) it is a (Serre) fibration when restricted to every cardinality stratum of Ran

b) one can lift homotopies in the base "that go from less singular to more singular strata": this should correspond to the idea that you can lift collisions of points in Ran to the algebraic datum parametrized in the BD-Grassmannians.
However, the fact that these properties hold seems to be "folklore". Does anyone know or see a clue to the proof?

Property (a) is clear to me, as it can be reduced to properties of the standard affine Grassmannian. Property (b) should almost equivalently be checked on the fiber $X^2\to Ran(X)$, as I think that understanding this case should provide the real nonobvious part of the statement.

In case it might be useful, I listed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364818/homotopy-type-of-the-affine-grassmannian-and-of-the-beilinson-drinfeld-grassmann) some more definitions and topological properties of the standard affine Grassmannian.